# how to access a variable in a python file passed from shell script ..?

Tags: python, shell

how to acsess a variable in a python file passed from shell script ..?

i am exporting a variable xyz from a shell script. Now i want to check it's value in python, file how to do that ?

I have tried using:

```
#Python
if '$xyz'
flag+= '-DVERSIONNUMBER'
```

Basically I have to create a macro if xyz holds some value and isn't empty. Can you suggest a way to do that?
My another doubt is that can we define a macro selectively in the python file i.e. if xyz is empty I don't want that flag to be defined, so that in the .c files I can check :

```
#if defined (VERSIONNUMBER)
//code
#else
//code    
#endif
```

In short following steps I have to execute :

- Pass xyz from shell.
- Check if it is not empty in Python and define a flag with value xyz
- Check if the flag is defined in python and execute some code in .c file.

Comment: When you say exporting variable, is the shell script turning this into an environment variable?

Comment: Passing arguments to python will put in the `sys.argv` list (pythons array). If you are passing a single argument, you can retreive it by: `import sys` `var = sys.argv[1]` (arrays start at 0, but sys.argv's first posistion is used as the file's name). If you just want to see if it exists or not you can do `if len(sys.argv) > 1`. If you want to set defaults or do anything more complicated, check out the builtin argparse module.

Comment: @CasualDemon, the `export` keyword in bash flags a shell variable to be exported to the environment. Thus, "exporting a variable from a shell script" has a specific technical meaning, as opposed to just referring to passing things around in general.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, noticed that right after I added it and saw your answer. Nice answer, you might want to change it to `.get('VERSIONNUMBER')` so that if it doesn't exist it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: @CasualDemon, oops -- good call, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Environment variables can be accessed via `os.environ['varname']`.

In your shell:

```
export VERSIONNUMBER=1
```

In your Python:

```
if os.environ.get('VERSIONNUMBER'):
   pass # do something here
```

Note that the environment is passed in one direction only -- from parents to children. Thus, *changing* the value for `os.environ['VERSIONNUMBER']` from within the Python script will have an effect on any subprocesses it starts (its children), but not the program that started it (its parent).